# How to pass 3 variable to threadpoolexecutor “map”

Tags: python, threading

The below code will show the issue with map func as the 3 args to login function very important

```
import requests
import random
import concurrent.futures

data = open("data.txt","r").read().splitlines()
#loding the username and password
url="example.com/login"
proxy= open("proxy.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
scheme = 'http://'

def login(data ,proxy,scheme):
    #for each row in the data to login with it

    datanow=data.split(":")
    user=datanow[0]
    password=datanow[1]

    prox =random.choice(proxy)
    prox=scheme+prox        

    headers={
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Length": "159",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Accept": "application/json",        
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    data={
    "LOG_USER_IN":"true",
    "user_name": user ,
    "password": password
        }
    proxies = {
                'http': prox
                } 
    r=requests.post(url , timeout=5 , headers = headers,data=data ,proxies=proxies )

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    ### error come here as map take only the second argument as the parameters
    executor.map(login ,data ,proxy,scheme)
    #printing the reaspose
    print(r)
```

If I use a bad way or the concurrent.futures is not the best way please told me because i am beginner

Comment: You should be able to use 3 arguments in a map call without any problems - what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
executor.map(lambda p: login(*p) , (data ,proxy, scheme))
```